# Terraform Azure AKS internal load balancer

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I deployed an Azure AKS cluster via the following terraform statements into an existing vnet. It worked, the AKS cluster is created with an Azure load balancer and an public IP address assigned to it. I need a setup with an internal Azure load balancer only. How do I have to change the terraform code to only get an internal Azure load balancer? Thanks

```hcl
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                 = "${var.tags.department}-${var.tags.stage}-${var.tags.environment}_aks"
  location             = var.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.aksrg.name
  dns_prefix           = lower("${var.tags.department}-${var.tags.stage}-${var.tags.environment}-aks")
  private_link_enabled = true
  node_resource_group  = "${var.tags.department}-${var.tags.stage}-${var.tags.environment}_aks_nodes_rg"

  linux_profile {
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    ssh_key {
      key_data = file("/ssh/id_rsa.pub") #ssh-keygen
    }
  }

  default_node_pool {
    name                  = "default"
    vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"
    enable_auto_scaling   = false
    enable_node_public_ip = false
    node_count            = 1
    vnet_subnet_id        = azurerm_subnet.akssubnet.id
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin     = "azure"
    service_cidr       = "172.100.0.0/24"
    dns_service_ip     = "172.100.0.10"
    docker_bridge_cidr = "172.101.0.1/16"
    load_balancer_sku  = "standard"
  }

  service_principal {
    client_id     = azurerm_azuread_service_principal.aks_sp.application_id
    client_secret = azurerm_azuread_service_principal_password.aks_sp_pwd.value
  }
  addon_profile {
    kube_dashboard {
      enabled = true
    }
  }
  role_based_access_control {
    enabled = false
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to create load balancer with azure, not with kubernetes?

Comment: In the first step, I want to have no Public facing Azure resources via Terraform deployment. But I get an Azure load balancer with an Public IP after the Terraform deployment (azurerm v.1.41).

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes please accept it. If you don't give any response, how to solve the problem? Or you just want to get the answer and do nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your issue, you can see that you set the network_profile of the AKS cluster like this:

```
network_profile {

    network_plugin = "azure"

    service_cidr = "172.100.0.0/24"

    dns_service_ip = "172.100.0.10"

    docker_bridge_cidr = "172.101.0.1/16"

    load_balancer_sku = "standard"

  }
```

And you set the property `load_balancer_sku`, it will create a `standard` type Load Balancer for you. And this property only can use the value `basic` and `standard`. So it seems it's impossible to create the AKS cluster without a Load Balancer. And you can see the [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11233) in Github. As it said, the newest CLI also cannot help you achieve that.

If you have more questions about this issue, please let me know. I'm glad if I can help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is configured in the Kubernetes LoadBalancer service using annotations. Specifically you need to add `service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"` to the spec of your `LoadBalancer` service.

This is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard#additional-customizations-via-kubernetes-annotations

Comment: any change to prevent TF creating a public interface?

Answer (score 1):

This public IP is used for outbound connectivity. To deny creating this IP, you need to specify parameter outbound_type  = "userDefinedRouting", and provide your network with route table attached.